# How to find out whether the remote versioned item is a directory or a file?

Tags: svn

Is there a utility like `ls -l` in Subversion?

The purpose is to differentiate between files and directories. There is `svn ls` command but it simply lists all files and directories so if a file is committed without extension it looks like a directory.

For example.

```
M/trunk/Database/Base
M/trunk/Database/Upgrade
M/trunk/Database/readme
```

`readme` is a file here.

Comment: "if a file is committed without extension it will look like a directory" - directories can be named `something.ext` too - making a directory look like a file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by a script that will merge the outputs of `svn status` and `ls -l`.

Comment: This will not work if you need to look at the repository via URL - it will only work against a working copy.

Comment: The script can be intelligent - if the current folder is not working copy, it will use only `ls -l`.

Comment: One of us is missing the OP's point. As I read it, he wants something *like* `ls -l` so that he can identify directories vs. files within a working copy. If it's not a working copy, he has no need for an svn command in the first place, and wouldn't be trying to use one (or a script that merged the two).

Comment: Correct. I was thinking ahead to replace the default `ls` with a `new ls` that combines the features of `svn st` and `ls -l`. If the pwd is not working copy, it simply defaults to `ls -l`. Anyway a good solution seems to be the one I proposed above (even if we do not replace the default ls)

Answer (score 0):

In the output of `svn ls`, any line ending with `/` is a directory. If there is no `/` and the end of an entry, it's a file.

You can also use the output of `svn ls --verbose` and parse it looking for an integer in the "file length" column (the one preceding the datestamp). If there is no integer, it's a directory. If there is one, it's a file.

Answer (score 0):

OK ... got it.. 
**svn info** is the answer

eg:

```
Path: /root/trunk/testproj
URL: https://my.svn.net/svn/testproj/trunk
Repository Root: https://my.svn.net/svn/testproj
Repository UUID: cdc0d28-0418-b024-f56a02f096e4
Revision: 100
**Node Kind: directory**
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: jack
Last Changed Rev: 100
Last Changed Date: 2013-06-10 14:11:08 +0530 (Mon, 10 Jun 2013)
```

Here 'Node Kind' gives the info i need .

Comment: Seems like a lot of extra work if you need to check every item in a directory to determine if it's a file or directory.

Comment: yaa m thinking of using it in a shell script . anyway there seems to be no better option other than this atleast for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`svn info <URL>`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/info/) command to find out whether the path represents a file or a directory.

Run the command `svn info http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools` and the result will be:

```
Path: tools
URL: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools
Relative URL: ^/subversion/trunk/tools
Repository Root: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf
Repository UUID: 13f79535-47bb-0310-9956-ffa450edef68
Revision: 1663737
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: danielsh
Last Changed Rev: 1663005
Last Changed Date: 2015-03-01 00:31:24 +0300 (Sun, 01 Mar 2015)
```

**"Node Kind: directory"** entry means that `/asf/subversion/trunk/tools` is a directory.

Run the command `svn info http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/README` and the result will be:

```
Path: README
Name: README
URL: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/README
Relative URL: ^/subversion/trunk/README
Repository Root: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf
Repository UUID: 13f79535-47bb-0310-9956-ffa450edef68
Revision: 1663738
Node Kind: file
Last Changed Author: danielsh
Last Changed Rev: 1242804
Last Changed Date: 2012-02-10 18:58:53 +0400 (Fri, 10 Feb 2012)
```

**"Node Kind: file"** entry means that `/asf/subversion/trunk/README` is a file.

---

You can add `--xml` command-line option to `svn info` command to get XMLed output which is easier to parse:

`svn info http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/README --xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>
<entry
   path="README"
   revision="1663740"
   kind="file">
<url>http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/README</url>
<relative-url>^/subversion/trunk/README</relative-url>
<repository>
<root>http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf</root>
<uuid>13f79535-47bb-0310-9956-ffa450edef68</uuid>
</repository>
<commit
   revision="1242804">
<author>danielsh</author>
<date>2012-02-10T14:58:53.499287Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</info>
```